# ip forward not working inside a netns on CentOS7

Tags: linux, networking, router, iptables, forward

I was trying to build a virtual network with a virtual machine and 2 virtual routers.

> VM -> Router1 -> Router2 -> External network

Router1 does SNAT and works well. Router2 is expected to do ip forwarding, but not working.

Here are details of Router2 I've checked. (Router2 is inside netns d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a.)

**NICs and addresses**

```html
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: qr-70aabff6-c8@if60: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:29:3b:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global qr-70aabff6-c8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe29:3bea/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: qg-30c10598-27@if63: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:fc:1b:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.10.52.82/24 brd 10.10.52.255 scope global qg-30c10598-27
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.52.158/32 brd 10.10.52.158 scope global qg-30c10598-27
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.52.73/32 brd 10.10.52.73 scope global qg-30c10598-27
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.52.68/32 brd 10.10.52.68 scope global qg-30c10598-27
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fefc:1b5b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**route rules**

```html
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a ip rule
0: from all lookup local 
32766: from all lookup main 
32767: from all lookup default 
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a ip route
default via 10.10.52.1 dev qg-30c10598-27 
10.10.52.0/24 dev qg-30c10598-27  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.52.82 
192.168.1.0/24 dev qr-70aabff6-c8  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
```

**forwarding is turned on**

```html
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a sysctl net.ipv4.conf.qr-70aabff6-c8.forwarding
net.ipv4.conf.qr-70aabff6-c8.forwarding = 1
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a sysctl net.ipv4.conf.qg-30c10598-27.forwarding
net.ipv4.conf.qg-30c10598-27.forwarding = 1
```

**iptables rules are cleared**

```html
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a iptables -t mangle -F
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a iptables -t nat -F
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a iptables -t filter -F
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a iptables -t mangle -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-FORWARD (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-INPUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-OUTPUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-POSTROUTING (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-PREROUTING (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-float-snat (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-floatingip (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-mark (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-scope (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a iptables -t nat -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-OUTPUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-POSTROUTING (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-PREROUTING (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-float-snat (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-snat (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-postrouting-bottom (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a iptables -t filter -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-filter-top (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-FORWARD (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-INPUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-OUTPUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-local (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain neutron-l3-agent-scope (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Finally when I ping 8.8.8.8 from the VM, the router can only see packets received, no packets forwarded.

```html
[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a tcpdump -i any -nn icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
14:00:37.138271 IP 10.10.52.140 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 9616, seq 10258, length 64
14:00:38.139298 IP 10.10.52.140 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 9616, seq 10259, length 64
14:00:39.140488 IP 10.10.52.140 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 9616, seq 10260, length 64
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank God. I finally found the answer after digging into the kernel source.  There is a little switch 'rp_filter' that tells the kernel to drop 'bad' packets. Here is the full description from the kernel doc:

```html
rp_filter - INTEGER
 0 - No source validation.
 1 - Strict mode as defined in RFC3704 Strict Reverse Path
     Each incoming packet is tested against the FIB and if the interface
     is not the best reverse path the packet check will fail.
     By default failed packets are discarded.
 2 - Loose mode as defined in RFC3704 Loose Reverse Path
     Each incoming packet's source address is also tested against the FIB
     and if the source address is not reachable via any interface
     the packet check will fail.

 Current recommended practice in RFC3704 is to enable strict mode
 to prevent IP spoofing from DDos attacks. If using asymmetric routing
 or other complicated routing, then loose mode is recommended.

 The max value from conf/{all,interface}/rp_filter is used
 when doing source validation on the {interface}.

 Default value is 0. Note that some distributions enable it
 in startup scripts.
```

In my circumstances, turning it off like this is good:

```html
ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
ip netns exec qrouter-d3dcb2df-f3ca-4079-a434-491b23f84b5a sysctl net.ipv4.conf.qr-70aabff6-c8.rp_filter=0
```